# Why Symfony dont use a Form to handle security component login?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-security

From document https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html that describe how to setup a login form that work with `Symfony Security` component, I am surprised to not see the use of `Symfony Form` component.

They render the form in pure HTML, and the form is handled by some magic, by the security component somewhere (and break the concept of Controller that should handle the HTTP request).

Is there a particular reason to not use a Form type here? (and also a controller).

Comment: It was done to avoid introducing a dependency on the Form component in the documentation.  The security component can of course be used outside of the Symfony framework.  Perfectly okay to use a form if you want.  As far as the controller part goes, there is actually quite a bit that goes on when an user authenticates.  It was basically easier to design and implement as a listener though I agree it is a bit disconcerting to get used to.

Comment: ho I see, so Symfony is missing something like a "security-form" component ^^ to glue security and form components. I see also that form CSRF is coming from security, so no duplicated code! So I should write a custom SymfonyFormAuthenticationListener based on https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/SimpleFormAuthenticationListener.php

Comment: If your only goal is to use the Form component for logging in then just make one and use it in the GET action in your login controller.  No need to do anything else.  The actual POST login handler won't care.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony security does not use forms as forms works with submitted data and most of the authentication methods is done using the HTTP Headers which a form does not have access.

Security component has 2 roles: Authentication and authorization. You are mentioning authentication in this question.

Authentication it is way more complex than just handling a form in a controller.

Only one of the authentication methods implies a form submit in symfony: UsernamePasswordToken and even that can be submitted as a http basic/digest authentication via a header.

Other ways of login/authentication/authorization is via the remember me token, sessions, oauth tokens, Json Web Tokens, SAML, etc.

The more flexible way is to just have a authentication system based in events, although this adds quite complexity to the system that has been addressed with Symfony Guard in Symfony 3.

[image]

https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html

Comment: Thanks you, my question was why Symfony dont use their Form component for that?

Comment: Because the form component only checks submited data and in most  cases the authentication is done by http headers.

Comment: I asked about login process only, when user submit a form, security component will handle it via https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/SimpleFormAuthenticationListener.php. I want a Symfony form because we are using it everywhere in the application.

Comment: In that class you have the author, if you want you can ask him directly. I'm more curious why he did not add an option resolver for the options. If you do you can post the answer here. Remember you are on a listener that it will be triggered on every request so the heavier you do it the slower it will get the whole symfony.

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote my own GuardAuthenticator that handle Symfony form (extends Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator):

[image: Symfony form guard authenticator]

This work like a charm! and the design team can use form easily.

Comment: Glad you got it working but I still don't see the need for a custom authenticater.  Configure the form_login section in security.yml and a regular Symfony form will work just fine.

Comment: Yes I admit this is quite the same thing, but I prefer use 100% Symfony Form, this is why there is a framework after all!

Comment: Sorry but I guess I am just not explaining myself very well.  You can use a 100% Symfony form with the built in security system.  No need for a custom authenticator.  But again, as long are your are happy with your solution then great.

Comment: Nop you are right, I used many times the ``form_login`` authenticator with a Symfony Form rendered, I was just curious to understand why. Also, another existential question (^_^), why they dont use ``Guard`` component here?

Comment: The Guard functionality is a fairly recent addition.  Maybe somewhere around 2.4 or so.  Before Guard, making a [custom authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) was more fun than developer should be allowed to have.  I guess they just decided to leave well enough alone.  Especially if you look at the FormLoginFactory in the SecurityBundle you can see all the options and what not that it supports.